# PayPal sandbox account not accepted by Easy Digital Downloads

Tags: paypal

I am using the Easy Digital Downloads WordPress plugin, with the PayPal plugin. I am testing with my sandbox account. I have been investigating an issue where entry of valid credit card results in an error:

"Error: Invalid Configuration This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration."

Obviously my first reaction was that this was an issue with my setup. But having spent a considerable amount of time with EDD support, it turns out that is just a misleading error. The reason I say this is because if I use a different account (the only thing that changes is the sandbox account credentials) then everything works juts fine.

I am grabbing the credentials from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/ and copy/pasting from Sandbox -> Accounts -> API Credentials. I have double-checked (and triple checked) I have copied all the information to EDD OK.

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this. EDD support has indicated that this is an PayPal account issue.

Comment: One more clue. If I add a single character to the end of my PayPal sandbox account in the plugin (making it an invalid account), I get a completely different error. So, the plugin seems to be talking to PayPal and it's a recognized account. So, it does seem there's something going on that is account-specific.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally comes when the account you are trying to accept the payments in is not a pro account .

You need to upgrade your sandbox account to pro . To do that , just login to the developer portal --> dashboard --> sandbox accounts . Select your sandbox account email address , click on profile -- > upgrade to pro -- > Enable .